# Why can't I access this Ext4 partition using FUSE?

Tags: macos, filesystem, mount, ext4

I have installed FUSE for OS X. During installation I ticked the "compatibility layer" option. I have rebooted after installation.

I have an external HDD with one NTFS partition and two Ext4 partitions. Operating systems are installed on the partitions.

I am only able to mount the NTFS partition. The Ext4 partitions appear in Disk Utility, but nothing happens when I try to mount them.

What can I do to access them?

Comment: Did you install the [fuse-ext2](https://github.com/alperakcan/fuse-ext2) package, or just FUSE for OS X? You need both to mount any Ext partitions. Assuming you did, try mounting from the command line and see what happens: `mount -t fuse-ext2 /dev/diskXsY /Volumes/YourDisk`

Comment: @robmathers That was the solution, thank you. You could post it as an answer.

Comment: @robmathers By the way, are these tools stable? Should I be worried about damage to my ext4 partitions? (More so than if I was dealing with FAT, HFS+, NTFS, etc?)

Comment: Glad that helped. It's hard to answer exactly how mature and stable they are, but generally reading should be pretty safe, but there's a potential for issues with writing. Ext2-fuse [recommends read-only](https://github.com/alperakcan/fuse-ext2#bugs) for example. For light use you're most likely fine, but if we're talking critical data, maybe find other solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to install the [fuse-ext2](https://github.com/alperakcan/fuse-ext2) package as well. FUSE is just the compatibility layer, it needs filesystem-specific implementations to be useful.